# Symfony 2 + JMSSecurityExtraBundle: @PreAuthorize('permitAll') doesn't work

Tags: symfony

I have a project with / put behind a firewall. However, I want one of my controllers to be "insecure", e.g display its contents regardless of authentication. But whatever I do, the bundle stays secure.

My current approach is:

**security.yml**:

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: true
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        BrokernetGroup\Platea\SecurityBundle\Entity\User:
            id: brokernet_group_platea_security.crypt_encoder

    role_hierarchy:

    providers:
        db_users:
            entity:
                class: BrokernetGroup\Platea\SecurityBundle\Entity\User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/login.html$
            security: false

        protected_area:
            pattern:  ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: /login-check.do
                login_path: /login.html
            logout:
                path:   /logout.do
                target: /

    access_control:
```

**Controller skeleton**:

```
<?php
namespace BrokernetGroup\Platea\InfoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation as SE;

/**
 * Description of InfoController
 *
 * @author Gergely Polonkai
 *
 * @SE\PreAuthorize("permitAll")
 */
class InfoController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="BrokernetGroupPlateaInfo_homepage", hostnamePattern="{hostname}", requirements={"hostname" = "%www_hostnames%"})
     * @Template
     */
    public function homepageAction()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `anonymous: ~` below the `protected_area:` in your security.yml file for enabling anonymous token